# Selenium PY - xpath - loop not working

Tags: python, class, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have a question about extracting the second element within a class by using Selenium and, particularly, `xpath`.
Looking at the image (sorry for not reporting the HTML by coding but it would be too long) I would extract the second item indexed "field content", that about the date (4th June 2018). However, there is another object before also indexed with "field content" : Cultures and Identity in Europe. Therefore, I have some problems in only extracting the date and put it in a Data frame as I tried to do in my code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw3el.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:xxx', chrome_options=option)
browser.get(url)
url= "https://www.mooc-list.com/countries/italy"
titles_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'views-row views-row-')]")
titles = [x.text for x in titles_element]
for i in titles_element:
    newtitle= i.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='views-field views-field-title']")
moocstitle = [x.text for x in newtitle]
for i in titles_element:
    area= i.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='field-content']")
areas = [x.text for x in area]
moocs = pd.DataFrame({'moocs': moocstitle,

                          'areas': areas
                       })

moocs.head(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I observe correctly, the list of class names that contain the date text are unique. The date text can be selected in two ways:

To select a class name that is **contained** inside multiple class names:

```
#if class name has spaces on both sides 
//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' test-class')]/span

#if class name has spaces on left side only(your example)
//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class)), ' views-field-field-start-date-text')]/span
```

To select **by the all class name(s)** of the specific class tag

```
//div[@class='views-field views-field-field-start-date-text')]/span
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for you suggestion! it runs, absolutely non sense the fact I forgot to consider this path "views-field views-field-field-start-date-text". However, in a more general case. how to selet the secnod element within a class with the same refenrece: in this case "field content". Is there a solution. Thank you again for your suggestion!

Comment: (//div[@class='field-content')])[1]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Xpath :

```
//a[contains(text(),'Cultures and Identities')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'field-title')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'start')]/span
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved all my problems. Loving python scraping but need to train more and more

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You can mark this answer as accepted by clicking on check mark which is just under the down vote button. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying this on selenium specifically (im using lxml but the xpaths should be the same), I think we can get far just on changing your xpath alone. For example this xpath can get you all the date strings:

```
'//div[contains(@class, "views-field-field-start-date-text")]/span'
```

You can then index into that:

```
result[2].text
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot to consider this path: "views-field views-field-field-start-date-text". thank you

Comment: @cruisepandey answer is probably the most specific to your case as it gets the exact string based on the text for your specific answer. Mine is a bit more general